# Exceptions handler

Tags: php, oop, exception

I have to develop an exception handler that should handle like 5 different type of exceptions. Let's call them simply `Ex1`, `Ex2`, `Ex3`...

I though of doing a single class called `ExHandler` which will be instantiated like this:

```
...
} catch (Ex1 $e) { $h = new ExHandler($e); $h->render(); }
catch (Ex2 $e) { $h = new ExHandler($e); $h->render(); }
catch (Ex3 $e) { $h = new ExHandler($e); $h->render(); }
...
```

And inside `ExHandler` manage each different Exception differently using `$e instance of Ex1, $e instance of Ex2, $e instance of Ex3`...

But It doesn't seems a very good practice to me. Is it good? Is there any other way of doing this?
Should I create an `Ex1Handler`, `Ex2Handler`, `Ex3Handler`...? My S.O.L.I.D spirit tells me something is just wrong here. What is it?

Comment: Im trying to think through your logic here, and it seems quite convoluted (+ alot of extra code for Exception handling). I tend to create custom Exception handlers for each class (other than finals), when I catch exceptions I rethrow them as standard Exceptions with my customer error messages, errors codes and backtrace created from my custom handlers. This way I pick up all Exceptions and, if needs be drill down into my code by calling methods in my extended Exception handlers.

Comment: @DavidBarker, One of these Exceptions is PDOException which is thrown via PDO. I can't wrap all my code or all the PDO functions with try-catch blocks so I think it's easier to just catch it and handle it. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't know much of PHP, but it seems that an overloaded "render" method would be more convenient. When you catch the exception you know its type. If PHP does not support overloading, you can create renderEx1, renderEx2 and so on.

Comment: @Jeff I use my own PDO wrapper as an extended class that uses three try/catch blocks to catch any PDOException and then rethrow these as normal Exceptions as well.

Comment: @DavidBarker, could you please make an example of it or just post your own so that I take a look at it? (I prefer it as an answer so that I can up vote or accept it...). Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff No problem, when I get some time today Ill put together a semi detailed answer for you on my methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to note before I answer this, that procedural programmers will look at this and think it's dumb :) but I can live with that, this is assuming an OOP application with HTML templating that outputs after the output_buffer is cleaned.

I always create a try/catch block encompassing the majority of my code in one call usually at the point where I start requiring other files as well as starting an output_buffer whilst in development.

```
ob_start();

try {
    switch($appPage) {
        case('work'):
            require_once('im_bored_at_work.php');
            break;
        case('home'):
            require_once('im_a_little_less_bored_at_home.php');
            break;
        default:
            require_once('on_the_fence.php');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception caught and apply formatting
}

$devOut = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

To give an example how I would handle the multiple exceptions you need to catch with a custom class

```
class CustomExceptionHandler extends Exception {

    private $msg;
    private $code;
    private $otherVars;

    public function __construct($msg,$code=0,$otherDebugVar=null){
        $this->msg = $msg != null ? $msg : "An unknown exception was thrown";
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->otherVars = $otherDebugVar;
        parent::__construct($msg,$code);
    }

    public function getOtherVars() {
        return $this->otherVars;
    }

}
```

The idea is to just keep the custom information within the exception object, and when you rethrow the exception at the end of a try/catch block as a standard exception you include the formatted custom message, it shouldn't really matter now which Exception handler picked up the original exception as all the info you will need will come downstream and be caught in the original try / catch block.

```
class BasicTemplate {
    private $template;
    private $path;
    private $contents;

    public function __construct($template, $path) {

        $this->template = $template;
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->buildTemplate();
    }

    private function buildTemplate() {

        if ($contents = @file_get_contents($this->path . $this->template)) {
            $this->contents = $contents;
        } else {
            $e = new CustomExceptionHandler("Message",2,$this->path . $this->template);
            // Do whatever else you want to do with custom exception handling class
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to catch your exception and rethrow it:

```
try {
    $html = new BasicTemplate($temp,$path);
} catch {CustomExceptionHandler $e) {
    throw new Exception("Message: {$e->getMessage()} Other Info: {$e->getOtherVars()}",$e->getCode());
}
```

That's the rough idea anyhow, hope it helps.